# Can room owners get back the ability to delete messages?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I am a room owner of a chat room. Sometimes, things escalate quickly, and it would be very useful for room owners to be able to delete problematic messages as they are posted.

Last time this happened, I tried to write a bot that would delete unwanted messages, almost like imposing a makeshift ban on the users who were posting them. This worked pretty well.

However, I noticed that the deletion stopped working a few hours ago. It seems that the team pushed out an update that prevents room owners from deleting messages from other users.

Can you please bring this feature back for room owners?

Comment: hmm. have we ever had the ability to delete chat messages that aren't our own?

Comment: @KevinB There was no UI for it, but the server allowed it. We fixed that vulnerability (if you want to call it that) yesterday, but rekire apparently exploited it and wants to continue doing that :)

Comment: @KevinB yes as room owner you could send the command and it got executed.

Comment: @balpha The intention is to remove garbage messages only like some offensive message or an unwanted gifs/png. We can have this feature with such limit ?

Comment: Because these messages easily gets flagged and seeks mod attention unnecessarily.

Comment: For what it is worth in SOCVR we have two extra gallery rooms with only write access for RO's where we move garbage/unwanted/handled messages to. I realize that is not the same as deletion but when it gets flagged it is out of the way of the main room anyway and clear that such message are not tolerated in the main room. Using these rooms as opposed to the generic trash/thrashcan is that the RO's also have control over those rooms.

Comment: Also - don't forget that mods are there if you need help with room moderation - if you're being repeatedly pestered or suffering an influx of rubbish that moving messages/warning and kicking just doesn't cover  then raise a custom mod chat flag and we'll take a look and help where we can. Also see: [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat)

Comment: Funny how whatever update there is, we always have someone to notice, like the re-indexing :)

Comment: If you don't fix it, it's a bug, but if you do fix it, it was an important feature that has been suddenly removed.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth that is software development :-D

Comment: I've got to be honest, my gut reaction is no. This was fixed because there were several ROs who were abusing it by hiding bad behavior of chat participants. I'd much rather abusive messages be sent to the Trashbin where there is still a record of them for mods to see the history of poor behavior. Hiding it doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @bluefeet I feel sorry that someone is abusing an *unintended* feature. However as a room owner you have responsibilities. I personally would expect that mods can read also deleted messages, so I see there no problem in deleting messages. I mean as a 10k rep user you can always see deleted posts on SE. Instead I see it as advantage to delete crap so it won't be indexed in Google or any other crawler and the sh*t will just be gone for ever.

Comment: @rekire You need 10k to see deleted content on the main site that requires time and effort put into it. A RO only needs 100 rep which doesn't require a lot of experience or know how on how things work on the site. Mods are also elected and given the ability to see deleted content to help with moderation issues, I don't that as a need for ROs. They can move messages to the trash as it should be.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1172/

Comment: @bluefeet as always, problematic room owners can be banned from creating or owning rooms. Thus preventing the issue entirely. I can see the content of deleted messages in the rooms I own by visiting the history page for that message, I have no reason to suspect that moderators would not have that privilege. The only thing that I see that would stand in the way is that deleted message stubs don't show up in the transcript for room owners (unfortunately), I don't know if the same can be said for moderators, but if there was an interface for it, that wouldn't be a problem either.

Comment: There are two or three rooms called 'trash' or 'trash bin'. Just move the messages there. That serves to remove the content from the room and still provide a reference for fellow room owners or the offender if you need to show them.